# how to get value of type "application/octet-stream" in http post method web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, advanced-rest-client

When uploading image through Advanced REST client app, I have chosen content type as "application/octet-stream"

And here is my code in Web Api controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Upload")]
        public Result Upload(Stream img)
        {
          //convertions here
        }
```

The issue is am receiving input parameter as null value.

[ARC app testing environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3kVb.jpg)

Could anyone help me out to fix this issue, please

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to debugg and see if you can get  this inside your function,  var stream = Request.Body;

Comment: Request.Body is not available only Request.Content is there

Comment: yes so add [frombody] in front of stream type

Comment: https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/web-api-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-6-asp-net-5/